# Error starting Nuxt.js app: No build files found

Tags: docker, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

```
$ npm run start

> app@1.2.3 start /home/app/ui/web
> nuxt start

FATAL  No build files found in /home/app/ui/web/.nuxt/dist/server.
Use either `nuxt build` or `builder.build()` or start nuxt in development mode.
```

Error happens when starting a Nuxt.js app in a Docker image that was built multi-stage:

1. `npm ci && npm run build` inside the build-stage image
2. copy the built app `.nuxt`, and also `package.json` and `node_modules` into the run-stage image

**Some details regarding the environment.**

Nuxt.js application mode is 'spa'. The missing files are really present inside the final image, no volumes/mounts have been used. OS user names are different between build-stage and run-stage images, however (hopefully) that should not be the case.

Nuxt.js 2.12.2, Node.js 14.16.0.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], including your `Dockerfile` and how you're starting the container?  In particular, are you overwriting the image's code with volumes or bind mounts?

Comment: @DavidMaze thank you for your swift answer, I've found the root cause and updated the question with the environment details. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nuxt.config.js` was missing.

After I've copied it into the run-stage image, and switched from `localhost` to a `0.0.0.0` for `server.host` property inside the `nuxt.config.js`, container is running fine:

```
> app@1.2.3 start /home/app/ui/web
> nuxt start

ℹ Listening on: http://172.17.0.2:3000/
```

Thus the required items for running a prod build in a server deployment mode are (seemingly) following:

```
/.nuxt
/node_modules
nuxt.config.js
package.json
```

The documentation is somehow vague regarding what should be included into the final artifact:
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/commands/#server-deployment

A different SO question that inspired the troubleshooting:
[Nuxt deployment error: server resources are not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485785/nuxt-deployment-error-server-resources-are-not-available)

### Update

Updated Nuxt to 2.15.3, switched from ad-hoc `npm` build to a reproducible build via `yarn`.

The build stage have become a `yarn install --frozen-lockfile && yarn build`. Also, copying `node_modules` from build stage into run stage brings development dependencies into prod, b/c prod build of Nuxt app requires development dependencies. Thus during a run stage, switched to a `yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production=true` instead of copying `node_modules` from a previous build stage.

The required items copied from a build stage for running a prod Nuxt app in a server deployment mode (https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/deployment-targets/#server-hosting) are thus following:

```
/.nuxt
nuxt.config.js
package.json
yarn.lock
```